# Separate Hours, Mins and Seconds in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I have created one alarm clock application.
In which, when user clicks on the Set Timer Button, Picker view gets called.
Picker view displays Hours, Mins and Seconds.
When User select them and clicks on Ok, then That Timer Button Value Gets changed.

For Example: 
If User Selects 2 Hours , 4 mins and 10 Seconds then

Button Label will be 02:04:10

Now i want to Separate all 3 things like 2 will be stored in one string, 4 will be in other and 10 in some other string.

What should i do here?
Can Anyone please help?

Comment: please take a look at nstimeformat

Comment: Why do you want each element stored in a string and not an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this think may be helped you ....

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"<your date format goes here"];
NSDate *Yourcurrenttime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string1];



    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSHourCalendarUnit |NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate: Yourcurrenttime];

    NSInteger hour = [components hour];
    NSInteger minutes = [components minute];
    NSInteger seconds = [components second];
```

And Store the all value in the string.

```
NSString *HourSTR =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",hour];
NSString *minutesSTR =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",minutes];
NSString *secondsSTR =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",seconds];
```

Answer (score 2):

i done one count Down timer like this way may be its useful for you

```
 -(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
 timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateCountdown) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
 }
```

**AND**

```
 -(void) updateCountdown 
 {

NSString *dateString = @"14-09-2012";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
// voila!
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];


NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];



NSDateComponents *componentsHours = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
NSDateComponents *componentMint = [calendar components:NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:now];    
NSDateComponents *componentSec = [calendar components:NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:now];        


NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *componentsDaysDiff = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                            fromDate:now
                                                              toDate:dateFromString
                                                             options:0];



lblDaysSetting.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",componentsDaysDiff.day];
lblHouresSetting.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",(24-componentsHours.hour)];    
lblMinitSetting.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",(60-componentMint.minute)];  
lblSecSetting.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d",(60-componentSec.second)];  



 }
```

now just set your logic